# select from same table but different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

I have table whic looks like

`from_type, from_id, to_type, to_id 
  A          12       B        15
  B          15       C        16`

 I tryed

```
select  A.FROM_TYPE,A. FROM_ID, B.TO_TYPE, B.TO_ID 
from  ITEM_LINK A   JOIN( select FROM_TYPE, FROM_ID, TO_TYPE, TO_ID 
                               from table
                              WHERE FROM_TYPE = 'B' and TO_ITEM_TYPE ='C')
  B ON A.TO_TYPE =B.FROM_TYPE
  where A.FROM_TYPE = 'A' and A.TO_TYPE ='B'
```

however this query doesn't work right , As an answer from this query i want to have

`from_type, from_id, to_type, to_id 
  A          12      C        16`

I don't need to have B in answer. also this query  will be join by FROM_ID FROM_TYPE A  in another query. Any ideas how to build this query?

My answer is not right  because its showing me something like this

`from_type, from_id, to_type, to_id 
  A          12       C        16
  A          12       C        17
  A          12       C        18`

which is not right  because TYPE A can connect to only one TYPE C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  select t1.`from_type`, t1.`from_id`, t2.`to_type`, t2.`to_id` from Table1 t1
   inner join table1 t2
   On t1.`to_type` = t2.`from_type`
   and t1.`to_id` = t2.`from_id`
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e84d6/2)

sorry didnt see its sql server

try that

```
  select t1.[from_type], t1.[from_id], t2.[to_type], t2.[to_id] from Table1 t1
  inner join table1 t2
  On t1.[to_type] = t2.[from_type]
  and t1.[to_id] = t2.[from_id]
```

[**DEMO for sqlserver**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0595e/2)

Comment: it doesn't  work trowing an error `The multi-part identifier "a.TO_ITEM_ID" could not be bound.`

Comment: Thanx a lot, actually first query works i changed the syntax and miss table identifier for ine of the parameters thats way it was trowing me error. Its working  properly right  now! thank you !